# EV SSL on main domain and Wildcard SSL for subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, wildcard

Can I have EV SSL for my main domain (say www.example.com) and Wilcard SSL for my subdomains (say eb1.example.com, eb2.example2 etc)?

If yes, then can you please let me know how to configure it?

If not, then please suggest me alternate methods.

All the subdomains and the domain will be hosted on Amazon and will have one IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can purchase an **EV SSL Certificate** for your main domain and **wildcard SSL certificate** for the sub domain names.

Please ensure that the Main domain has a **dedicated IP Address** and it is not shared with the sub domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can have use multiple certificates at the same time which overlap in the subjects like in your case. To have multiple certificates for the same IP address the serve and client must support [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Most modern server and browsers do. But older browser like IE8 on XP do not and support within non-browser application is mixed.